# Sorting a list of ExpanoObejct by the properties using reflection

Tags: vb.net, reflection, expandoobject

I want to sort a `List(Of MyDynamicObject)` by it's properties, where `MyDynamicObject` is an `ExpandoObject`. I have the property names as strings, so I need to use  some sort of reflection to pass them.

Let's say I have a list:

```
MyList = New List(Of Entry)
```

where `Entry` has a property `MyProperty_01`.
 Now I want to sort `MyList` by the objects property `MyProperty_01`.

In case of static objects and no reflection, I would do something like this this:

```
MyList = MyList.OrderBy(Function(x) x.MyProperty_01).ToList
```

Now if I need to pass the property name as a string, I can do this:

```
Dim MyPropertyName As String = "MyProperty_01"
MyList = MyList.OrderBy(Function(x) GetType(Entry).GetProperty(MyPropertyName).GetValue(x)).ToList
```

where `Entry` is the objects class reference.

How can I do this with an `ExpandoObject`? I don't have a class reference in case of an `ExpandoObject`.

So this doesn't work anymore.

```
Dim MyPropertyName As String = "MyProperty01"
MyList = MyList.OrderBy(Function(x) GetType().GetProperty(MyPropertyName).GetValue(x)).ToList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one possible way, but not using reflection. Since `ExpandoObject` implements [`IDictionary(Of String, Object).Item`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3) interface, you can cast the object to that interface type and access properties by property name string, just like you access value by the corresponding string key from a dictionary :

```
Dim MyPropertyName As String = "MyProperty01"
MyList = MyList.OrderBy(Function(x) CType(x, IDictionary(Of String, Object))(MyPropertyName)).ToList
```